# Web scraping simultaneous request

Tags: python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

```
from urllib import request
import urllib
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

page = request.urlopen("http://someurl.ulr").read()
soup = (page,"lxml")
```

Now this process is very slow because it makes one request parses data, 
goes through the specified steps and then we go back to making the request.

```
- for example



for links in findAll('a'):
    print (links.href)
```

and then we go back to making the request because we want to scrape another URL, how does one speed up this process?

Should I store the whole source code of the URL in a file and then do the necessary operations (parse through, find data we need) ---?

I've got this idea because from a DoS(Denial of Service) script that
 uses import socks and threads for making a large amount of requests.

*Note: This is only an idea,*
Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Comment: yes, use [`scrapy`](https://scrapy.org)

Comment: No I love my soupy, I'll find a way won't let my soupy down.

Comment: you can use `soup` with `scrapy`. Scrapy only adds async requests to the table.

Comment: Oh, thank you then. I've seen scrapy but I just love beautifulsoup thought I needed to mitigate the whole code but that should be fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most efficient way to this ist most probably using asyncio and at one point spawning as many python processes as you have threads.

[asyncio documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/asyncio.html)

and call your script like that:

```
for i in $(seq $(nproc)); do python yourscript.py $entry; done
```

This will lead to a massive speed improvement. In order to further increase the speed of processing you could use a regex parser instead of Beautifulsoup, this gave me a speedup of about 5 times.

You could as well use a specialized library for this task, e.g. [scrapy](https://scrapy.org/)

Comment: Huh well that's very useful, I'll learn more about this. 
I'm aware I can't just spawn many instances of the same thing because it will do just the same thing and thank you,  eLRuLL just pointed me to scrapy will look how can I intergrate this.
I got one more question for you, 
If I try to scrape for example linkedin what kind of solution would you recommend to bypass bot-security (not inclouding proxies and time-delays) I'm grateful for the help !

Comment: Highly depends on the bot-security implementation. I can't give you any advice without knowing this specifically. On method would be running in those bot security things and solve them.